# I need help sending JSON via POST and getting a response

Tags: javascript, json, post

I need to send a json object via post and i cannot get it working. I have it so that it returns successfully but the response is empty and i cannot figure out why things i have tried are

```
new Ajax.Request("http://twittersentiment.appspot.com/api/bulkClassifyJsonRequests", {
method: "post",
postBody:JSONstring,
onSuccess: function(transport){
var response = transport.responseText;
alert("Success@ \n" + transport.responseText + "no response");
},
onFailure: function(){alert("try again")}
});
```

and

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST","http://twittersentiment.appspot.com/api/bulkClassifyJsonRequests",true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(http.readyState == 4)
{
    if(http.status == 200)
    {
        document.write(http.response.data);
}
else
{
    alert(http.statusText);
}
} 
};
http.send(JSONstring);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is preventing that call from happening. You could install a proxy server in between to make those calls, and return the output to your AJAX script. See [Why You Need a Proxy](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html) for more details.

Comment: What the heck? You just posted the same answer as me and even linked to the same article.

Comment: @Drackir - there is a service known as Wikipedia. There is another service known as Google. Google is used to search everything. Wikipedia is like an information store of everything. When you search for something in Google, most times the first link that shows up is from Wikipedia. Hence, the same links. By the way, one of your upvotes is mine. You're welcome!

Comment: @Sydenam - I am not a copy-pasta gangsta.

Comment: Regardless of the link (point ceded), you still posted the same answer as I did half an hour after me. It's not about the rep, it's just rude and unnecessary. If you wanted to share the proxy link, why not add it as a comment? What's the point of filling SO with duplicate answers?

Comment: @Drackir - I didn't mean to duplicate your answer. This is one of those answers where I wanted to add more detail like using YQL or Yahoo Pipes as a proxy to avoid setting up your own proxy, but didn't cause I am lazy. And then this answer was accepted, and you commented on mine. Regardless, I will delete my answer. Yikes, I can't until OP accepts yours.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to send a cross-domain request (it violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). This is a security issue and is not allowed by browsers. If twittersentiment.appspot.com provides a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) option, you can utilize that instead. Otherwise, you'll have to look into proxying through your website or similar ideas.

**Edit**
Note: This only applies to using AJAX. Also, After looking at their [api docs](https://sites.google.com/site/twittersentimenthelp/api), it seems they do support JSONP for their "Classification Service". Perhaps you can use it with the "Bulk Classification Service (JSON)" as well?